# AddAsync(driveItem) does not return

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The `.AddAsync(driveItem)` in the following code never returns. Could anyone shed some light on this?

```cs
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(App.ClientId)
    .Build();

DeviceCodeProvider authProvider = new DeviceCodeProvider(
    publicClientApplication,
    new string[] { "Files.ReadWrite.All" });

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
DriveItem driveItem = new DriveItem
{
    Name = "Foo",
    Folder = new Folder { },
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    { { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "fail" }
    }
};
await graphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(driveItem);
```

**[Edit 1]**

I have tried folder names other than "Foo", tried names of existing or non-existing folders to no avail.

I also tried "rename" instead of "fail" for "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" to no avail.

I also tried without AdditionalData to no avail.
**[Edit 2]**
I decided to wait for the method to return for a while (more than 10 minutes), and it finally threw an exception:

> Code: generalException Message: An error occurred sending the request.
>
> Source    "Microsoft.Graph.Core"

```
  at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__31`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Inner Exception:

> Code: generalException Message: Unexpected exception occured while
>   authenticating the request.

```
   at Microsoft.Graph.Auth.DeviceCodeProvider.<GetNewAccessTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Auth.DeviceCodeProvider.<AuthenticateRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.<SendAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__62.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
```

**[Edit 3]**

The following code has exactly the same problem:

```
IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage children = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

This looks like a general problem for the Graph SDK.

**[Edit 4]**

I played the app registration of Azure Active Directory, and got the following most inner exception:

```
AADSTS70000: The provided value for the input parameter 'device_code' is not valid.
Trace ID: 7067d5e9-d811-49ed-9b8b-7a0b9a0c4c00
Correlation ID: a4faa514-debc-47dc-8ef3-0b9853949e28
Timestamp: 2020-01-11 06:47:36Z
```

Again, I have to wait for more than 10 minutes for the exception to be thrown.

**[Edit 5]**
Not sure why exactly the same calls using [Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Graph-Controls) work perfectly.

```
await provider.Graph.Me.Drive.Root.Children
.Request()
.AddAsync(driveItem);
```

Comment: There's a pretty good chance that somewhere further up your call stack, your code is calling `Wait()` or `Result` on a task, which [would cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) if done on the UI thread.

Comment: @StephenCleary Here is what happens: 1. A button is clicked. 2. In the button handler: await MethodAAsync(); await MethodBAsync(); 3. MethodBAsync() has the code in question.   In light of your comment, I commented out MethodAAsync(), but the problem remains.  The UWP app has been in Microsoft Store for 2 year.  I was forced to switch from UWP Toolkit to Graph SDK today because UWP Toolkit's OneDrive functions no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this isn't returning, but `Camera Roll` is one of the [special folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get-specialfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (and therefore a reserved folder name). There are a small number of these that get automatically generated either when the `Drive` is provisioned or when a specific service connects for the first time (i.e. "Camera Roll" is created by the OneDrive app):

- Documents
- Photos
- Camera Roll
- App Root
- Music

In order to retrieve the Camera Roll folder, you request it by it's "id":

```
GET /me/drive/special/cameraroll
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  I have tried with other folder names to no avail.   Let me edit the question by adding the variations that I have tried.  I will change "Camera roll" to avoid possible conflicts.