# Microsoft Graph exception: AADSTS70000: The provided value for the input parameter 'device_code' is not valid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Could any Microsoft Graph expert offer a tip on the meaning of the following exception:

```
AADSTS70000: The provided value for the input parameter 'device_code' is not valid.
Trace ID: 7067d5e9-d811-49ed-9b8b-7a0b9a0c4c00
Correlation ID: a4faa514-debc-47dc-8ef3-0b9853949e28
Timestamp: 2020-01-11 06:47:36Z
```

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59686896/355456). The AddAsync(driveItem) of the following code throws the exception (the most inner exception) **after waiting for more than 10 minutes**.

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(App.ClientId)
    .Build();

DeviceCodeProvider authProvider = new DeviceCodeProvider(
    publicClientApplication,
    new string[] { "Files.ReadWrite.All" });

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
DriveItem driveItem = new DriveItem
{
    Name = "Foo",
    Folder = new Folder { },
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    { { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "fail" }
    }
};
await graphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(driveItem);
```

**[Edit 1]**

Here is the registered application and the ID used for PublicClientApplicationBuilder:
[image]

**[Edit 2]**
Not sure why exactly the same calls using [Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59686896/355456) work perfectly.

```
await provider.Graph.Me.Drive.Root.Children
.Request()
.AddAsync(driveItem);
```

Comment: Are you able to make other calls to this tenant using this Client Id and and a device code?  The code you are showing looks good to me.

Comment: @DarrelMiller The code is for an app that has been in the store for two years.  but was copied straight from Microsoft Graph / Reference / v1.0 reference / Files /...   I first used a ClientId that was used flawlessly for 2 years with UWP Toolkit's OneDrive functions. I later registered an application from scratch following Microsoft documents for UWP apps, but the outcome is the same with the new ClientId.  No, I have not been able to make any calls (e.g. graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request()GetAsync()).  Waiting for more than 10 minutes to get an exception is frustrating.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Since I am not able to add an image in a comment, I edited the question by adding a screenshot of Azure > Home > Default Directory > App registrations

Comment: It sounds like what happens when the user doesn't complete the auth flow within the 10 minute period. You mentioned this is a UWP app, but you're using the device code flow? Typically UWP apps would use the InteractiveAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: @JasonJohnston That makes sense. I am new to Graph, and have been gathering references from all kinds of difference places.  I should be all set for now because I have returned to the beloved Toolkit that the app used for 2 years for handling OneDrive. I switched to Graph SDK, but have just found they have a pre-release version for Graph that works like a charm as the old OneDrive functions.